# Are there any standards for defining sets of Kafka topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka topics can be created via command line tools or API.

In large systems where there are multiple topics and multiple environments (dev/qa/prod etc.) it becomes necessary to control the creation of topics and their configuration (partitions, etc.). For example, we may want to maintain a shell script file under source control that checks whether a topic already exists and creates it if it doesn't. That same script can then be applied to each successive environment (perhaps automatically as part of CI/CD) to create or modify topics a needed.

Are there any standard file formats or tools for maintaining Kafka topic topologies?

Answer (score 1):

No out-of-box script is offered by Kafka, but you could write a simple SHELL script to implement this, as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
TOPIC=$1
ZK_CONNECT=localhost:2181
KAFKA_PATH=<your Kafka install directory>
LIST=`$KAFKA_PATH/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $ZK_CONNECT --list`
arr=$(echo $LIST|tr " ", "\n")
for each in ${arr[*]}
do
    if [[ $each == $TOPIC ]]; then 
            echo "Already exists..."
            exit
    fi
done

$KAFKA_PATH/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $ZK_CONNECT --create --topic \
    $TOPIC --partitions <num_partitions> --replication-factor <num_replicas>
```

Comment: Thanks! Scripting is indeed one way to do it. I was wondering if there are any tools out there that would build a Kafka topology from configuration files from example.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a Kafka topic 'topology' ?